# How to sum the other cells in a column with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

In cell A1 I can't write `=SUM(A:A)` (Circular reference). If I write `=SUM(A2:A15)` when I insert A16 the result won't be affected. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up all cells in the entire column except the one cell in the same column that you put the formula in (namely `A1`), use

```
SUM(A2:A1048576)
```

for MS Office 2007 and later, or use

```
SUM(A2:A65536)
```

for MS Office 2003 and earlier.

Comment: Will that work for `MEAN` too? Will it consider the blank lines?

Comment: I think you mean `AVERAGE()` function. Yes, it works for it as well. It does not evaluate the empty cells.

Comment: Yes, `Average`. `Mean` is the Octave name for the same method.

Answer (score 3):

You could move the =SUM(A:A) to another column or you could set A1 as =SUM(A2:A20000).

Comment: +1.  Note that it is considered bad form to have the sum of an entire column *in that same column*, so the first solution (move the sum to another column) would be your best bet.